# Why App Sandbox option inside Capabilities pane of Xcode target is not visible?

Tags: ios, xcode, settings, target

In the Xcode 6.2, inside Capabilities pane of Target settings, App Sandbox option is not visible. 
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sandboxing option only shows up for Mac OS targets. iOS targets are always sandboxed.